# The Proxy server recieved an invalid reponse. ( How to catch that exception and redirect to error page

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, proxy, timeout, weblogic

I have a web application deployed in Weblogic server. In my service class its firing a  query and due to huge data query takes too much time  to complete. So I get an error on screen The Proxy server recieved an invalid reponse from upstream server. I  have already added try catch block and catching Exception

But  it doesnt catch an exception . I want to catch this error and redirect to error page. Any Idea? Note: I do not need query optimization and I do not want to change any timeout or configuration. I just want to catch this and do some logic on my own

Comment: The error is thrown by the proxy server, thats the reason your exception handling is not working. Better do the operation asynchronously.

Comment: It can be handled asynchronously,  I know but  is there any way to handle that exception ? because I want to catch it and redirect it somewhere

Comment: Since the error is thrown by the proxy server you wont have control over that in your application.

Comment: Ok so is there any way I can keep my application alive?

Comment: You need to solve the upstream problem, rather than implementing a piece of software with 1,000 crutches.